# Adding text in Tool Help of Python script tool

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, arccatalog, documentation

How do I add some text in the section "Tool help" in a Script tool?

I leave a screenshot in case there are doubts about what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an also create and use compiled help files to make more detailed help documentation for your scripting tool including images.

[See this link](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/referencing-a-compiled-help-file.htm) from ESRI on using or referencing compiled help files.

[See this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/htmlhelp/create-a-help-project) for creating help files.

[And this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/htmlhelp/compile-a-help-project) on compiling the help file.

Answer (score 4):

If you need help with the entire tool you can add the details in the script property description:

[image]

[image]

And if you need to add details for each parameter follow the below:

[image]

Right Click on the tool and open the item description:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]